# Google Chrome Freezing in External Monitor

Tags: macos, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, google-chrome-canary

I'm using a Macbook with Retina Screen with a DELL LED Monitor connect via HDMI Cable.

I usually keep Google Chrome Canary open in External Monitor with 8-10 tabs open and Keep my Editor in Macbook's own screen to work. But If I leave my laptop Idle for few minutes or it goes in Sleep mode and After waking it up my Google Chrome Canary in External Monitor stops responding. I can drag it to here and here but All tabs will be unresponsive. Only option would be to Force close and restart it again.

My chrome version is 39.0.2136.0 canary (64-bit) and OSX version is 10.9.4 with 8 GB RAM.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Switching to the Laptop-monitor, and back to the External monitor again, may show that one of the Chrome tabs opened a dialog.  Now you can close that dialog and continue working.  It remains a hassle though.  I don't consider this an answer to you Q. Merely a workaround.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the time I dock my laptop with the lid closed and use my external screen. Every time I undocked my laptop, chrome froze and I had to kill the process. (this is on a Windows 7 machine)

This fixed it for me

```
Chrome -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Uncheck "Use harware acceleration when available"
```

Comment: also worked on a PC (Windows 7)

Comment: This had been bugging me for weeks. Thanks a ton.

Comment: worked on ubuntu 18 LTS too

Comment: Worked on Kubuntu 21.04, thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

Try any of the following:

1. Try disabling internal Chrome plugin or external plugin; or
2. Try to uninstall and install; or
3. The problem may be associated with Flash version.

Comment: Which internal plugin?

Comment: I hope this below links helps :

Comment: Which links? I assume you forgot to add links

Comment: ah I am sorry.. please find below
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1074231